# BrowseForFolder Function in Inno Setup Doesn't Show Mapped Drives

Tags: inno-setup, mapped-drive

I'm using Inno Setup v6.0.5. I want to allow the user to select a folder so I use BrowseForFolder. The problem is that the resulting dialog does not show any mapped drives. It shows the Network folder but on my machine (and presumably others) it won't open for some reason. Is there a way to get the BrowseForFolder dialog to show mapped drives or is there another method that can be used to allow the user to select a path with a mapped drive?

Comment: Run `net use` from a command prompt for your current user, and then run `net use` from an elevated command window. (My suspicion is that 1: Your installer is running elevated and 2: The mapped drives do not show in the elevated window.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart yes you are correct. When adding PrivilegesRequired=lowest to the script I now see the mapped drives.

Answer (score 3):

The core of the problem is not that Inno Setup doesn't show mapped drives, but rather that elevated and unelevated processes do not, by default, share mapped drives. see this article:

[Mapped drives are not available from an elevated prompt when UAC is configured to "Prompt for credentials" in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3035277/) (3035277)

What this KB article is saying, in a convoluted way, is that mapped drives between elevated and non-elevated sessions are not shared. You can tell Windows that you want to share the mappings by setting the `EnableLinkedConnections` registry value:

Hive: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`
Subkey: `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
Value Name: `EnableLinkedConnections`
Value Data: `1`
Data type: `REG_DWORD`

Changing this setting requires a reboot, so you can't use it for just your individual installer -- and I don't recommend [using a global state to manage a local problem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081211-00/?p=19873) anyway.

Based on your comment:

> I'm installing data files to the network, the software is installed on their PC. It's the answer if it solves the problem

It sounds like perhaps you could solve this problem by using a separate user-based installer that only installs the data files: Just use `PrivilegesRequired=lowest` in the `[Setup]` section and then the problem of drive mappings never arises.

Comment: I can't be asking users to set registry values though and when trying to temporarily change this key via scripting it doesn't work, I still can't see mapped drives.

Comment: I'm installing data files to the network, the software is installed on their PC. It's the answer if it solves the problem.